# Why a user who has permission to delete a model returns false for has_perm(app.delete_modelname)

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using django admin interface for an application. I have some models in an app named 'books'.There are two users 'manager' and 'employee' other than admin (with superuser status).
The 'employee' user can only add models. The 'manager' can add, change and delete every models in books app.I gave the permissions through the admin interface. But in shell has_perm(books.delete_ModelName) for 'manager' returns False.

```
>>> u = User.objects.get(username__exact="manager")
>>> u.has_perm("books.delete_ModelName")
False
```

When giving superstatus to 'manager' through admin interface has_perm(books.delete_ModelName) returns True. Why this happens? I want to set access to a specific page based on this permission. Is there any work around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the problem solved. The problem was with the ModelName. if the name of a model is 'ModelName', it is dumped as modelname in permissions. So here it should be

```
>>> u.has_perm("books.delete_modelname")
```